# Formal writing, scholarly citation: 'Given in italics' or 'given italics'?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence

Generally, regarding scholarly citation, I would say

> As a general rule, any work that is published or produced under its own title is given **in** italics.

However, yesterday I found another version of this phrase, without 'in':

> As a general rule, any work that is published or produced under its own title is given italics.

The second version is probably free of *redundant* word, but on the other side it's less clear to me (I'm not native speaker). Which version is better for formal writing?

Probably a better question: what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you could make the phrase simpler still if you dropped *given* and just said *its own title is in italics*.

---

There is no practical difference between the two versions of your sentence, however there is a grammatical difference.

> The present was **given** wrapping paper.

This means that wrapping paper was applied *to* the present. You are describing an action that has been done to something.

> Its own title is given italics.
>   → Italics are applied to the title.

---

> The present was **given** ***in*** wrapping paper.

This means that the present (that was given) was contained *inside* wrapping paper. You are simply describing the thing itself.

> Its own title is given in italics.
>   → The title uses an italicized font.

Comment: The character that you used doesn't display on my computer (nor my phone). I switched it to some other arrow.

Comment: @Laurel Strange. I had been using Unicode 1F806. I've switched to what I *think* is what you used: 2192. If it's the same (and you can see it now), I guess it means I should be sticking to 4-character codes.

Comment: It says "Edit removed during grace period" so what's still displaying right now *is* my edit. In any case, I can still see the character.

Comment: @Laurel That was actually me. I overwrote your characters, but saving it didn't result in it changing anything. (Which seemed to indicate I'd replaced them with the same ones.) But I wanted to make sure, so I deleted them, saved the edit, then pasted the different Unicode version in a new edit a few seconds later. I think it's the same. And thanks for mentioning it. :)